Application crash on WebCoreTestSupport::allowsAnySSLCertificate
When running an JavaFx application (from IntelliJ), using a webView/webengine, the application crashes when the webapp does (multiple) redirects ...
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x000000033fc621bc, pid=25361, tid=259
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-21.0.4+7 (21.0.4+7) (build 21.0.4+7-LTS)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-21.0.4+7 (21.0.4+7-LTS, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, bsd-aarch64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libjfxwebkit.dylib+0xc421bc]  WebCoreTestSupport::allowsAnySSLCertificate()+0x8e21f4
#
# No core dump will be written. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# (removed)
[19.190s][warning][os] Loading hsdis library failed
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://github.com/adoptium/adoptium-support/issues
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:56125', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6:SIGABRT)  

Code
@FXML 
public WebView webView;

WebEngine webEngine;
String portalUrl = "some url";
String redirectUrl = "some url";

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle){

    // Load webengine
    webEngine = webView.getEngine();

    addListeners();
}

...

private void addListeners() {

    // Add listener to the url property
    // If url changes, login was executed
    webEngine.locationProperty().addListener(
            new ChangeListener<String>() {
                @Override public void changed(ObservableValue ov, String oldState, String newState) {
                    if(oldState != null){
                        if (!oldState.equals(newState)) {

                            if(newState.indexOf(redirectUrl) == 0){ 
                                // We are on our final destination
                                // Do stuff
                                
                            }else if(newState.indexOf("?error=")>-1){
                                webEngine.load(portalUrl);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            });

    if(!"".equals(portalUrl)){
        webEngine.load(portalUrl);
    }
}

We are working on a macBook pro M3, using Os X, Adoption Java 21.0.4 LTS JDK, JavaFX 21.04. We tried using java/javaFX 17 without any luck.

Try your application on another machine type (e.g. not OS X M series).  If you want further assistance here, you will need to provide a [mcve] that replicates the issue via copy and paste with no change or addition, also the address provided should resolve and not be "some url".

Loading a new web page in a change listener for the location will change the location, which might lead to unpredictable behavior.  You might be able to avoid that by surrounding the load operation call in the change listener with Platform.runLater, for example Platform.runLater(() -> webEngine.load(portalUrl))

It seems upgrading to JavaFX 23 or 24 pre-release solved the issue ...
